# Clearing The whole database In Neo4j Enterprise edition

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, cql

I'm using Neo4j Enterprise Edition. I want to clear the whole database I have created before . I mean Every single Node and it's relationships and also properties So I found this syntax on Neo4j book I ran the syntax :

```
MATCH (a)
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[r]-()
DELETE a, r
```

But still can see the properties on the property keys part 
what's wrong?

What should I do so that even properties get deleted?

[image: Neo4j Browser]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neo4j Browser just show the data returned from `CALL db.propertyKeys()`. Currently the procedure `db.propertyKeys()` is returning unused properties, as you can see in this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/10941) at Neo4j Repo.

That is: your database is totally empty, but Neo4j Browser still showing the properties that existed in your database at some point of time.

Since you are deleting all your nodes and relationships, you can alternatively delete all content of <`neo4j-home>/data/databases/graph.db/` folder and restart Neo4j service. But you will need to recreate all indexes, constraints and do authentication again.

---

*Tip: Currently you can use [DETACH DELETE](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/delete/#delete-delete-a-node-with-all-its-relationships) to delete a node and any relationship going to or from it. So instead of the query yo wrote you can use:*

```
match (node)
detach delete node
```